# PHP upgraded to 5.3.8 - Can't install/upgrade extensions

Tags: centos5, yum, php, php53

I managed to [upgrade](http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/install_or_upgrade_php_53_for_centos_5) php from 5.2.10 to 5.3.8 in CentOS 5.4. Some of the extensions were lost in the process (mbstring, mysql).

One quick run for:

```
yum list installed | grep php
```

Returns:

- php.x86_64
- php-cli.x86_64
- php-common.x86_64
- php-pear.noarch
- php-pecl-igbinary.x86_64
- php-pecl-memcached.x86_64

When I try to install new extensions:

```
yum install php-mbstring
```

I get this error message:

> Transaction Summary
>   ================================================================================ Install       3 Package(s) Upgrade       0 Package(s)
>
> Total size: 3.6 M Is this ok [y/N]: y Downloading Packages: Running
>   rpm_check_debug Running Transaction Test Finished Transaction Test
>
> Transaction Check Error:   package
>   php-common-5.3.8-5.el5.remi.1.x86_64 (which is newer than
>   php-common-5.2.10-1.el5.centos.i386) is already installed   file
>   /etc/php.ini from install of php-common-5.2.10-1.el5.centos.i386
>   conflicts with file from package php-common-5.3.8-5.el5.remi.1.x86_64

Practically the same happens with **yum install php-mysql**

How do I get rid of those old versions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that the `remi` repo is disabled by the default, verify with `yum repolist` or `grep enabled /etc/yum.repos.d/remi.repo`. When you install `php-mbstring`, it is pulling from `base` repo. So, try this:

```
# yum --enablerepo=remi install php-mbstring
```